# The Lebesgue integral of certain function on the set of irrational numbers of the unit interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

We define a function on $J$, the set of irrational points of the interval $(0,1)$ with $$f(0/a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots)=0/a_2a_1a_4a_3\ldots$$ What is the value of  Lebesgue integral $$\int_J f $$  Furthermore is there an algebraic formulation for $f$?

Comment: Is $0/a_1a_2a_3a_4$ supposed to be a decimal expansion?

Comment: @EricWofsey  Yes  it is  the unique   decimal  expansion.

Comment: Are you swapping the digits in each successive pair past the decimal point?

Comment: @MPW  I  am  sorry  I  do not  understand your  question. We swap with the formula  $0/a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6\ldots  \mapsto  0/a_2a_1a_4a_3a_6a_5\ldots $.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was uncertain of the pattern, you have clarified it now.

Comment: Cf. the Rademacher functions.

Comment: Oops, good catch copperhat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: (Thanks to @EricWofsey for catching an egregious error.)

Let $d_k(x)$ be the $k$th
 element of decimal expansion of $x$. Then
$\int d_k = {1 \over 10} (0+1+\cdots + 9)= {9 \over 2}$.

We have $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k(x) {1 \over 10^k}$.

Note that for any nice functions $g_k$ that satisfy $\int g_k = {9 \over 2}$ we have
$\int ( \sum_{k=1}^\infty g_k(x) {1 \over 10^k} ) dx =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int g_k(x) {1 \over 10^k} dx = {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: If  we integrate  your  formula $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k(x) {1 \over 10^k}$ we  get  contradiction assuming $\int  d_k=1/10$

Comment: Let me check...

Comment: That's 9/2, not 9.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Something is wrong with my computation

Comment: @EricWofsey: Thanks for catching that, I was computing the integral as $\int 1 dx$ instead of $\int x dx$ to compute the constant. I didn't actually compute the sum :-(.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot blame lack of caffeine or abundance of wine...

Comment: @copper.hat  Thank  you  very  much  for  this  very  interesting answer.Sorry I  did  not  read the  first  version of  your  answer  carefully so  I  did not  got your idea.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a probabilistic take on essentially the same method as copper.hat's answer.  Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ is the same as the probability measure where you independently choose each digit uniformly from $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$.  Now, $f(x)$ (thought of as a random variable) has this same property: each digit of $f(x)$ is chosen independently and uniformly from $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$, since the digits of $f(x)$ are just the digits of $x$ in a different order.  This means that random variable $f(x)$ has the same probability distribution as the identity random variable $g(x)=x$, and so they have the same expectation.  That is, $$\int_{J} f(x)\,dx=\int_J x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: There is a wonderful monograph by Marc Kac (Statistical Independence in Probability, Analysis and Number Theory, I think) that starts with a similar argument (base 2). Worth a glance I believe...

Comment: @Eric  Thank  you  very  much  for  your  very interesting answer. i  am  sorry that i  can not  accept  two  answers simultaneously